# Maximum length property for an editable div

Tags: html, contenteditable, maxlength

I have an HTML div element in my application as follows:

```
<div id="DivId" contenteditable="true" style="border:1px solid black"></div>
```

I need to **limit the number of characters that can be typed in the div**. Like giving the *maxlength* attribute a to textbox. How can I do this? It would be very helpful if I would be able to do it without using JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do this without JavaScript

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript. The `maxlength` property is not valid on `div` elements.

Answer (score -1):

There are some CSS attributes like `max-height` or `max-width` which do limit the width for block level elements.

So you can code this out like this:

```
<div style='max-width:100px'>Content</div>
<span style='max-width:100px; display:block;'>Content</span>
```

But be careful, as they do not properly support [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6): Refer to *[min-width and max-width](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/width.html)*.

But if you just mean the length of the content, I am sorry to say that you can't do that in HTML. You need to use a piece of JavaScript to do this. Take a look at jQuery; it's really easy to do.