# Issue in html Editable element after click

Tags: javascript

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="s1" contenteditable="true" style="height: 58px; width: 58px; overflow: hidden; color:white; position: relative;">&#160;</div>
```

I want to remove space by click on this div and also restrict with input only single alpha character.

please help

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the effort you've put in before asking and you will get better help.

Comment: `<input type="text" maxlength="67" size="152"></input>`

form input is not working in IPAD so I am using

`<div class="s1" contenteditable="true" style="height: 58px; width: 48px; overflow: hidden; color:white; position: relative; text-transform: uppercase">&#160;</div>`

this for takking a input from user and also make restriction for that user can only enter sing alpha character

please help

Comment: If you want to do this without using JS you *have* to use `<input>`. The attribute you want then is `maxlength`. This cannot be set on a `<div>`, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876085/max-length-property-for-an-editable-div. Otherwise you have to use JS. And there are quite a handful of resources for how to do that.